# Metrics / HTTP requests/responses are not showing up in Azure Application Insights dashboard for my nodejs express app

Tags: node.js, express, azure-application-insights, remix.run, appinsights

Currently using Azure App insights in a NodeJS app (specifically a Remix app using Express). After initializing the library, I am not seeing metrics show up on my Application Insights Dashboard nor the "Performance" tab

[image]

I've verified that the library is working, by going to "Transaction Search" and making a search for various metrics in my app and they show up there.

Answer (score 0):

For some reason, the library isn't properly registering capturing my ingoing and outgoing http requests. To solve this, I had to manually track requests/responses at the root of the app like so:

```js
// server.js
app.all("*", (req, res, next) => {
    /**
     * App insights normally would track all requests by default after initialization, but for some reason its not working in this app.
     * I have manually called `trackNodeHttpRequest` below to get all our requests/responses analyzed and showing up on our dashboard.
     * https://github.com/microsoft/ApplicationInsights-node.js
     */
    appInsights.defaultClient.trackNodeHttpRequest({
        request: req,
        response: res
    });
})
```

My actual server.js code file: https://github.com/remix-run/remix/discussions/4499